# single instance/injection of $mdToast in a base class

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I have a specific question about putting a single instance of $mdToast (from Angular Material) into a base class (Typescript).  I have five tabs in my UI and gave each a separate controller instance (i.e., separate inject and ctor declarations).  It made sense to move the $mdToast declaration into a base class rather than separately declare it everywhere.  You will see the base class has it's own "$inject" but apparently that is getting superseded by the one on the derived class.  I am just trying to figure out the cleanest way to move $mdToast to a common base class.  What is the best way?  Here is what my code currently looks like.

Note the original $mdToast lines are commented out:

```
export class MainController extends BaseController {
static $inject = [
  'tableService',
  '$mdSidenav', 
  //'$mdToast', 
  '$mdDialog', 
  '$mdMedia',
  '$mdBottomSheet'];

constructor(
  private tableService: ITableService,
  private $mdSidenav: angular.material.ISidenavService,
  //private $mdToast: angular.material.IToastService,
  private $mdDialog: angular.material.IDialogService,
  private $mdMedia: angular.material.IMedia,
  private $mdBottomSheet: angular.material.IBottomSheetService) {
  super();
  var self = this;
}}
```

with the following base class. Note the injection of $mdToast and declaration of the $mdToast outside of the constructor.

```
export class BaseController {
static $inject = [
  '$mdToast'];

constructor(
  ) {
  var self = this;
}

private $mdToast: angular.material.IToastService;

openToast(message: string): void {
  this.$mdToast.show(
    this.$mdToast.simple()
      .textContent(message)
      .position('top right')
      .hideDelay(3000)
  );
}}
```

I saw a clever use of $injector elsewhere in SO but it did not work for me.  All responses cheerfully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a pattern like this one:

```
export class BaseController {
    static $inject = [...];
    ...
}

export class MainController extends BaseController {
    static $inject = [...BaseController.$inject,
      ...
    ];

    constructor(...deps) {
        const superDeps = BaseController.$inject.map((dep, i) => deps[i]);

        super(...superDeps);

        const thisDeps = deps.slice(superDeps.length);
        const thisDepNames = this.constructor.$inject.slice(superDeps.length);
        ...


    }

    ...
}
```

It may be packed into some base class for injectables or decorator for convenience if it is used more than once or twice, but it is always about parsing two arrays, `$inject` and `deps`, and assigning dependencies to `this`.

This method is not type-safe.

For TypeScript it is preferable to keep the things WET but type-safe. We always want to have the dependencies for parent class coming first for consistency:

```
export class BaseController {
    static $inject = ['$mdToast'];

    constructor(protected $mdToast: angular.material.IToastService) { ... }
}

export class MainController extends BaseController {
    static $inject = [
      '$mdToast'

      'tableService',
      ...  
    ];

    constructor(
        $mdToast: angular.material.IToastService,

        private tableService: ITableService,
        ...
    ) {
        super($mdToast);
    }}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting wisdom in your statements.  You gave me a lot to consider.  The second example still suffers from having to inject $mdToast twice which I was trying to avoid.  How can I insure I get only one instance of $mdToast across all classes that inherit from BaseController? (btw, i upvoted)

Comment: Dupe `$mdToast` is the right thing here. It will be passed as constructor argument by injector anyway (this could be fixed with class decorator but it isn't worth it, to be honest). But it should be assigned to `this` only once and it can't override visibility (notice that there's `protected $mdToast` in parent class constructor but only `$mdToast` in child class constructor). Sure, `$mdToast` will be injected only once per controller instance, it doesn't matter if the class was inherited or not, that's how inheritance works.

Comment: During the rush of the weekend and all the refugees from Hurricane Matthew I decided to implement your changes and they work exactly as promised.  I still hate having to be WET but your comment about it being the best way to keep TypeScript type-safe resonated to me.  I come from a hard-core C++/Java/C# background and thinking this way in Javascript/TypeScript is a good place where I need to be more flexible than I have been in the past.

Comment: Sure, DI can be really neat by handling $inject array and constructor args with decorators and base classes (see goo.gl/ubLAqy for example), this works great for ES* and Babel but is type unsafe in TS (may be tolerable, depending on how much is gained from DRY/WET trade-off). The question doesn't show anything WET enough to abandon type safety, but maybe your real case is different.

Answer (score 1):

This method is a hack, for sure, but it will get the job done is a pretty dry way. Leverage ES6's import/export statements to make this service available where you need it.

```
export let $injector;

class injectorConfig {
    static $inject = ['$injector'];
    constructor (private $originalInjector) {
        $injector = $originalInjector;
    }
}

app.config(injectorConfig);
```

Then your BaseController.ts file would look like this

```
import {$injector} from '../yourfilename';

export class BaseController {
    private $mdToast = $injector.get('$mdToast');
    constructor( ) {
        var self = this;
    }
}
```

Just because it works doesn't mean you should lean on it, but in situations like these I think this technique makes sense. Bear in mind that the $injector will not be available until Angular runs this config block, so you can't use it in providers or any other code that runs before the config block runs.

Comment: This looks like a clean way to ensure a singleton value for $mdToast.  Thanks!